# CiviCRM upgrade paths

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I have Civicrm 5.3.0 on Wordpress. -  It says need to upgrade a security patch.  Should it be 5.3.1 or 4.6.38 first?  Want to end up with 5.3.2

Answer (score 3):

You can upgrade to 5.3.2 (and that will then automatically include 5.3.1 - the security release)